# PHP - Pagination and place results is a table

Tags: php, html, pagination, html-table

I have tried my hand at some pagination but it gives me very unexpected results....

The first is that it on the first page of the pagination it seems to override the CSS and align all divs to the right hand side of the page... when you then click 'next' to view the next three results and so on the page goes back as per the CSS tells it!

The second problem is that the table displaying the results doesn't seem to work. The very first result on each page of the pagination is in  the table, the next two results (three results per page) are displayed on the page however below and not in the table!

The code is quite long but here we go:

```
<?php
session_start();
if ( !isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
header("Location:index.php");
exit();
}

//connect to database

require "dbconn.php";


$per_page = 3;
$start = $_GET['start'];





$sort = @$_POST['order'];  
if (!empty($sort)) {
$query = "SELECT bookname, bookauthor, bookpub, bookisbn
            FROM booktable
            ORDER BY ".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['order'])." ASC";
}
 else { 
$query = "SELECT bookname, bookauthor, bookpub, bookisbn 
                FROM booktable 
                ORDER BY bookname ASC"; 
}


$results = mysql_query($query)
            or die (mysql_error());

$record_count = mysql_num_rows($results);
if (!$start)
   $start = 0;

$get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM booktable LIMIT $start, $per_page");
?>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['showerror']))
$errorcode = $_GET['showerror'];
else
$errorcode = 0;
?>
```

Then I will cut out all the unnecesary html

```
<div id="mid">

<?php
echo "<table border='2px'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>";

echo "</th>";
echo "<th>";
echo "Book Title";
echo "</th>";
echo "<th>";
echo "Book Author";
echo "</th>";
echo "<th>";
echo "Book Publisher";
echo "</th>";
echo "<th>";
echo "Book ISBN";
echo "</th>";
echo "<th>";

echo "</th>";
echo "</tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get))
{
 // get data
 $bookname = $row['bookname'];
 $bookauthor = $row['bookauthor'];
 $bookpub = $row['bookpub'];
 $bookisbn = $row['bookisbn'];



    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<a href='addtolist.php?bookname=".$bookname."&bookauthor=".$bookauthor."&bookpub=".$bookpub."&bookisbn=".$bookisbn."'>Add to basket</a>";

    echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo $bookname;
    echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo $bookauthor;
    echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo $bookpub;
    echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo $bookisbn;
    echo "</td>";

    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";

}

$prev = $start - $per_page;
$next = $start + $per_page;

if (!($start<=0))
       echo "<a href='products.php?start=$prev'>Prev</a> ";

       //set variable for first page number
$i=1;

//show page numbers
for ($x = 0; $x < $record_count; $x = $x + $per_page)
{
 if ($start != $x)
   echo "<a href='products.php?start=$x'>$i</a>";
 else
    echo "<a href='products.php?start=$x'><b>$i</b></a>";
 $i++;
}

//show next button
if (!($start >= $record_count - $per_page))
       echo "<a href='products.php?start=$next'>Next</a>";
?>



<?php echo $record_count; ?>
```

This is how the page looks (image 1) (the table border shows the problem)

[image: image1]

As I said before I also get the problem when the list first gets displayed and the page ends up looking like this: (image2)

[image: image2]

You can see how they differ!

I hope that I have made sense!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, you have your `</table>` tag in your `while` loop.  Change that and see if everything else falls into place.

Comment: Thats brilliant thank you... it is always the most simple thing that sort it I find!

Any ideas on the first page looking a little sque whiff? The table sorts out my table problem but the first page looking strange is still there (the images)

Comment: The problem is an undefined index 'start' but Im not sure how to go about changing or fixing this

Comment: dont worry, fixed with !isset to set start with a dummy booleon value!